# applying style.background color on button inside template in Component in Angular 8

Tags: angular

I wonder about Angular versions and their changes. I am learning Angular through a course on Udemy and installed Angular 8.
Now, according to course, I'm using style.backgroundColor on button inside template in Component.ts file. But it is not working. There is no error.

courses.component.ts

```
@Component(

{
    selector : 'courses',
    template : `

    <button   [style.backgroundColor] = 'red' class = "btn btn-primary"  [class.isActive] = 
    "isActive">save1</button>

    `    
  }
```

It is called style binding. Why it is not working? Is it related to Angular version?

Comment: Do you have `red` as variable or, are you using it as `string`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have done a style binding. Since you use red as string, you should wrap that string with `""`

```
[style.backgroundColor]="'red'"
```

else, you can define a variable in ts,

```
colorRed ='red'
```

then bind it in html

```
[style.backgroundColor]='colorRed'
```

Comment: One more thing, I want to know. When I press '.' after style, it doesn't show backgroundColor in the available methods list. Why?  It shows multiple things, but not backgroundColor.

Comment: I use Visual Studio Code